# Double line spacing in cas-sc formatted latex for Elseiver

Tags: els-cas

I am having trouble proof reading my document in single spaced.  How can I get double spaced? I am using the cas-cs documentclass on Overleaf.

For older version of the template I've found `review` recommended, but this doesn't appear to have any effect (documentation says it increases the baselineskip even with the current version but I can't see any difference).

I have tried using

- `setspace` package (no effect),
- `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` (it has some effect, but not what I want changed - the spacing between lines)
- `\linespread{1.5}`

I couldn't find an obvious command in the cls or sty files.  Any idea what I should be looking for? or what I can do to change this?

Comment: Thanks @campa That solved it - putting `\doublespacing` after `\maketitle`.  If you want to post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `cas-sc.cls` redefines `\maketitle` to execute `\MaketitleBox`, which is defined as

```
\NewDocumentCommand \MaketitleBox { }
{
  \tex_def:D \baselinestretch{1}
  \group_begin:
  \@title
  \group_end: 
  % OTHER STUFF
}
```

(Or variations thereof depending on some class options.)
I have no knowledge of `expl3` whatsoever but I think I can safely guess that the first bit is `\def`ining `\baselinestrech` to 1. Since this doesn't occur in a group, the definition is global. Using `\doublespacing` in the preamble will thus be useless.  As long as you don't care about the title page, the rest of the document can be set to double spacing by issuing `\doublespacing` *after* `\maketitle`.

Comment: About the `expl3` part: all(ish) TeX primitives `\foo` are renamed to `\tex_foo:D`, and the `D` specifically means `Do not use`, so yes, that's a copy of `\def` which shouldn't be used in code. A direct replacement for that would be `\cs_set:Npn \baselinestretch {1}`, or better, `\tl_set:Nn \baselinestretch {1}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik OK, I admit I lied a bit: I _did_ know that much `;-)`. I've made it more or less up to page 10 of the `expl3` documentation before I gave up...

Comment: Ooh, sneaky ;-)

Comment: why do not suscess? \usepackage{etoolbox} \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\baselinestretch{1}}{\baselinestretch{2}}{}{}

Comment: @higyg Try `\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn \patchcmd ... \ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother`.  This space is reserved for answers though; could you please delete?