# Can't double the line space of abstract in cas-sc formatted latex for elseiver

Tags: setspace, els-cas

I have trouble in using the cas-sc LaTeX template when my manuscript was sent back. The editor replied:

Type the **whole** manuscript with double line spacing.

I referenced [Campa's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519799/double-line-spacing-in-cas-sc-formatted-latex-for-elseiver) and added `\doublespacing` after `\maketitle` and I also added `\doublespacing` after `\keywords`. but no matter what I do, the **ABSTRACT** cannot be double spaced. The following code is the minimum samples for the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\let\printorcid\relax
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { stm / mktitle } { nologo }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \let\WriteBookmarks\relax
    \def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
    \def\textpagefraction{.001} 
    % Main title of the paper
    \title [mode = title]{This is title}  
    
    %%%%%%% second author %%%%%%%
    \author[1]{A person}
    \ead{aperson@outlook.com}
    \credit{}
    
    %%%%%%% Corresponding author %%%%%%%
    \cormark[1]
    \cortext[1]{Corresponding author.}

    
    %%%%%%% affiliations %%%%%%%
    \affiliation[1]{organization={organization},
        city={city},
        postcode={000000}, 
        country={country}}

    
    
    % Here goes the abstract
\begin{abstract}
this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract 
\end{abstract}
    
\begin{keywords}
    \doublespacing
    \sep keywords
    \sep keywords
    \sep keywords 
    \sep keywords
    \sep keywords
\end{keywords}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \doublespacing
\section{Introduction}
this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro this is intro 
\end{document}
```

This is the complied PDF.
[image]

`cas-sc.cls` can be downloaded [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates)

Comment: The `els-cas` suite is essentially a collection of bugs. It's hard to understand why a journal wants you to follow some specification that the class they force you to use doesn't offer.

Comment: @egreg haha yep, it's a tough time to deal with these so many issues, even i want to use Microsoft Word to resubmit the manuscript ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\doublespacing` is fragile, use it with `\protect`:

```tex
\begin{abstract}
  \protect\doublespacing
  this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract this is abstract
\end{abstract}
```

More information on `\protect` on [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/316068)